# Can anyone help me convert this MySQL statement into Linq lambda?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

I need help converting this query into linq.

```
select Title from titles
INNER JOIN UserTitles on UserTitles.TitleId = titles.TitleId
where UserTitles.UserId = currentUserId
```

so that i can loop the user titles:

example: Name, BS, BA, PHD

when i have these tables:

Users:

```
+---------------+----------+
| currentUserId | UserName |
+---------------+----------+
|             1 | Dave     |
+---------------+----------+
```

Titles:

```
+---------+-------+
| TitleId | Title |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | BS    |
|       2 | MD    |
|       3 | PHD   |
|       4 | BA    |
+---------+-------+
```

UserTitles:

```
+--------+---------+
| UserId | TitleId |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       1 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
+--------+---------+
```

**EDIT**

in my controller i have this:

```
IEnumerable<String> thisresult = _contentService.Titles
.Join(_contentService.UserTitles.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId),
t => t.Id,
ut => ut.TitleId,
(t, ut) => t.TitleString);

var model = new ManageUserViewModel()
        {
            Titlelist = thisresult
        };


        return View(model);
```

In my ViewModel i have this:

```
public IEnumerable<String> Titlelist { get; set; }
```

In my View i have this:

```
@foreach (var title in Model.Titlelist)
            {
                @Html.Raw(title)
            }
```

And i get this:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Specified method is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result=db.titles
  .Join(db.UserTitles.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId),
    t=>t.TitleId,
    ut=>ut.TitleId,
    (t,ut)=>ut.Title);
```

If using Entity Framework, with properly set up Users, and Titles tables with the appropriate navigation properties, it would be:

```
var result=db.Users
  .Where(u=>u.UserId == currentUserId)
  .Select(u=>u.Titles);
```

Comment: first one looks great. Im not sure how to put that to an enumerable list. I tried adding .ToList after and got an error "specified method is not supported"

Comment: public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FindUserTitles(int currentUserId)
{
var result =_contentService.Titles.Join(_contentService.UserTitles.Where(a => a.UserId == currentUserId), x => x.Id, y => y.TitleId,
(x, y) => new { x, y }).Select(t => new SelectListItem { Value = t.x.TitleString }).ToList();
return new SelectList(result, "Value");
}

var model = new ManageUserViewModel()
{Titlelist = FindUserTitles(currentUserId)};

return View(model);

In ViewModel: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titlelist { get; set; }
In View:@foreach (var title in Model.Titlelist){ @Html.Raw(title.Value)}

Comment: That looks ok to me, although I admit I'm not the best at converting to/from SelectList from memory.

Comment: yeah i think i should be using IEnumerable<string> instead. Its still giving me that error.

Comment: Where does it say the error is coming from?  Perhaps simplifying the problem down a bit instead of stringing along the result may pinpoint it better for you.  I just tested the Join on some sample tables here, and it actually returns a `DbQuery<String>`, which you can call `.ToList()` on to get `List<String>`

Comment: I added an update to the question of where exactly i get the error. see under "EDIT" maybe this helps.